# Hook in wp.media to add a new tab

Tags: plugin-development, themes, theme-customizer

This is an issue coming up while creating a plugin. I want to add a tab to the `wp.media.view.MediaFrame.Select` modal or if a general approach helps:

> In the customizer I want to hook in any modal that comes up using wp.media just to add an `alert()` for example.

This is almost it and I am already stuck in tracing what builds those modals and how to hook in.
What I see is:

- `wp.media().frame.on('open', ...)` can not be used as the frame only exists after clicking a button.
- Fallback may be to rewrite `wp.media()` but that doesn't sound like a sane solution.

What I don't want is:

- "Use `media_upload_tabs` or `media_upload_tab_slug`" because such PHP is not respected in the customizer.
- "Hook in every button and handle the click"
- "Look for frames via window.Timeout every second"
- Hacky solutions are welcome to find out what is possible but won't help as THE solution.

Thanks in advance to all wp.media experts here! :)